# Using variable to add key's to table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to use a table and add new data(another table) to it by using the name of a variable as key, and adding that key to the table. My first approach was:

```
local table
var = read()
print(var.." "..type(var))
table[var] = {name = var, foo = bar}
```

Unfortunally this causes an error(index expected, got nil). The print line in front of the table does print a value along with the type string if I enter a string value, yet it says it gets a nil in the line with the table. An bigger code snippet from the actual code(From the minecraft ComputerCraft mod):

```
m = peripheral.wrap("right")
m.clear()
m.setCursorPos(1,1)

mline = 1

bgcolor = colors.white
txtcolor = colors.black

debugbg = colors.green
debugtxt = colors.lightGreen

mainscreen = true
searchscreen = false
newitemscreen = false
newitemconfirmation = false
running = true

recipes = {}
temp_recipe = {}
 --end of variable declaration part, start of function declarations

function write(text,x,y,cl,bg) --custom writing function
  term.setCursorPos(x,y)
  term.setBackgroundColor(bg)
  term.setTextColor(cl)
  term.write(text)
  term.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor)
  term.setTextColor(txtcolor)
end

...

function newItem()
  temp_recipe = {}
  write("Name of the item: ",1,3,txtcolor,bgcolor)
  local item = read()
  write("Amount of items: ",1,4,txtcolor,bgcolor)
  local itemAmount = read()
  write("Amount of items types needet for crafting: ",1,5,txtcolor,bgcolor)
  local ingredientCount = read()
  local ingredientList = {}
  for iC = 1,ingredientCount,1 do
    write("Name of crafting component "..iC..": ",1,6,txtcolor,bgcolor)
    ingredient = read()
    write("Amount of crafting component "..iC..": ",1,7,txtcolor,bgcolor)
   ingredientAmount = read()
   ingredientList[ingredient] = {name = ingredient, amount = ingredientAmount}
  end
>>>>>   temp_recipe[item] = {name = item, amount = itemAmount, ingredients = ingredientList} -- Line that causes the error
  term.setCursorPos(1,8)
  printRecipe(temp_recipe["name"],item) -- irrelevant function to display the entered data
end
```

Is there a way to find a solution around this problem? The code is needet inside a function to assign multiple data entrys to the table, which then are accessible using the key representing the name.

Comment: What's the ```read``` function?

Answer (score 1):

You never create the `table` table. So you can't assign into it.

You want `local table = {}` or `table = {var = {name = var, foo = bar}}`.

Also don't use `table` as a variable name. It shadows/hides the `table` module.

Comment: the name table was just as an example. The table is being declared and assigned in the actual code, but outside the function. I just forgot to mention it in the code. When writing table = {[var] = {etc}} it does in fact add an key named after the value of var, but when trying the code it always seems to remove all other entries of the table. I dont know if this may originate from other functions of the code.

Comment: So your *actual* question is **entirely** different then then one you actually asked? You do realize that's entirely unhelpful right? You also realize that `tab = {[var] = "value"}` is creating a **new** table and storing it in the variable? And not setting the `var` key *in* `tab` right? Because assigning to a table key is `tab[key]` as you clearly are aware.

Comment: If I would write table{var = {data}} it would create a key named "var" and add that to the table. Writing tab[var] = {} causes the error with the index expected, got nil.

Comment: `tab[var] = {}` is the correct way to do what you want. It causes the error you are getting in your posted code because `table` doesn't actually exist. Show us the **real** code and the **real** error and maybe we can help with **that** case instead of this one.

Comment: It is the real error, and the table is declared like this:
dataList = {}

Comment: Then either `dataList` isn't in scope where you are using it or the `var` variable you are using in the real code doesn't actually have a value. Can you show us the real code? (Or at least something *much* more closely modeled after it?) Because if you can't then I don't know how I can help more.

Comment: Also at this point I'd probably argue that that would be a different question and this one should either be accepted or deleted (once that one is asked at least).

Answer (score 0):

To assign new key/values to a table in Lua, you surround the key with [] and assign a value to it with the assignment (=) operator. Example:

```
local tab = {}
local index = 5
local value = 10
tab[index] = value
```

Your error tells me you're assigning to a nil index (which isn't directly possible). So read must be returning a nil value.

Without any further information I am afraid I cannot help.

Comment: Like I already mentioned, the print method I set between the read() and the table assignment returned a string variable. Yet it says it got a nil